# DJANGO: Running SQL query using cursor in project.settings.py file

Tags: python, django, django-settings

In my project, I have made some setting fields within the "settings.py" file configurable by exposing them to the user via an environment file. So the user can modify the values on the .env file, and that is then used to update the setting fields within the main project settings.py file.
I want to improve this by migrating some of this values to the database, so users can set their values interactively via the product's UI instead of having to modify the .env. I have taken the following approach:

- After the default database has been declared in the DATABASES dictionary, I isntantiate a `connection.cursor()` to run a raw SQL query that retrieves the settings from the database, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).
- I manipulate the results of the cursor to construct a dictionary in which keys are setting identifiers and values are the relevant values from the database, as set by the user.
- This dictionary is then used to assign the appropriate value to each Django setting variable (i.e. `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`, `MEDIA_ROOT`, etc.). So at each setting variable instead of doing a `getenv`, I retrieve the value from the dictionary using the relevant key.

I have observed the code's behavior within settings.py, and I can see that each setting value gets assigned to the correct variable, identically to how it was when using the previous .env approach. The problem is that when these setting variables are accessed in the code via `django.conf.settings` or by direct import (`from project.settings import SETTING`), their value is an empty string, as if it has not been declared in the first place.

I have noticed that settings declared before the cursor is instantiated (regardless of whether their value was hardcoded or retrieved from the .env) work fine. Settings after the cursor seem to not maintain their state outside the settings.py file.

Can anyone please enlighten me as to why using a cursor within settings.py essentially invalidates all setting fields declared after it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue. The problem was that I was using Django's `connection` model (`from django.db import connection`), which performs the SQL query on the default database. Since this was running within settings.py while the project was still in its set-up process, it caused the strange behavior described above.

Solution: Instead of using `django.db.connection` (a Django model) to perform the query, I used Python's `pyodbc` library instead, which is the database engine used in the project. With `pyodbc` I was able to establish a connection to the database and run my query (as described [here](https://datatofish.com/how-to-connect-python-to-sql-server-using-pyodbc/)) regardless of Django's state.